# Обновление связанных записей

Tags: sql, база-данных, delphi

Для получения записей используется запрос:

```
SELECT
  E.ID,
  E.SecondName,
  E.FirstName,
  E.MiddleName,
  E.Phone AS Телефон,
  P.Title AS Должность,
  E1.SecondName + ' '+ E1.FirstName AS Наставник,
  E.Address AS Адрес
FROM (Employee AS E INNER JOIN [Position] AS P ON E.PositionID = P.ID)
INNER JOIN Employee AS E1 ON E.MentorID = E1.ID;
```

Записи отображаются с помощью dbedit.

Как сделать редактирование записей Наставник и  Должность? Пробовал через DBLookupcombobox, пока не очень понятно, DBLookupcombobox просто ничего не отображает. Делать через sql запросы?

Comment: вы прочитайте хотя бы для начала как этим компонентом пользоваться, может и вопросы отпадут сразу. lookupCombobox привязывается к основному датасорсу, для него же указывается поле внешнего ключа `dataField`, далее нужно указать источник записей для выпадающего списка - `listSource` и указываются ключевое поле `keyField` и отображаемое `listField`. очевидно, джойн внешних таблиц к основному запросу не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде стало понятно.